# Проблема с флагами js

Tags: javascript

Есть разметка, в которой по очереди меняются предметы. Сперва записывается в item1, затем в item0, потом опять в item1 и так далее.

Проблема в том что не могу сделать вывод предмета который только что добавился. Пока что сделаю проверку в какой `div` записывается, но не работает

```js
(function() {
  let flag = true;
  let item = [document.getElementById("item0"), document.getElementById("item1")];
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('link')) {
      if (flag ? item[0] : item[1]) {
        c("0");
      } else {
        c("1");
      }
      flag = !flag;
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<h1 id="item0">Div 1</h1>
<h1 id="item1">Div 2</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Использование `classList` предпологает наличие атрибута `class`, в вашем случае он отсутсвовал.

```js
(function() {
  let flag = true;
  let item = [document.getElementById("item0"), document.getElementById("item1")];

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  function c(str) {
    console.log('Entered c...');
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    if (e.target.classList.contains('link')) {

      if (flag ? item[0] : item[1]) {
        c("0");
      } else {
        c("1");
      }
      flag = !flag;
      console.log(flag); // debugg
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<!-------- Doesn't have class link -------->
<h1 id="item0" class="item00">Div 1</h1>
<h1 id="item1">Div 2</h1>
<!-------- Has class link -------->
<div class="link">With link class</div>
```

---

Есть такой вариант.

```js
(function() {
  let flag = true;
  let item = [document.getElementById("item0"), document.getElementById("item1")];

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  function c(index) {
     // Hide/Show current element
    item[index].classList.add('show');
    item[index].classList.remove('hide');
    // Hide other element
    item[index ? 0 : 1].classList.add('hide');

  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('link')) {
      if (flag) {
        c(0);
      } else {
        c(1);
      }
      flag = !flag;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-------- Doesn't have class link -------->
<h1 id="item0" class="hide">Div 1</h1>
<h1 id="item1">Div 2</h1>
<!-------- Has class link -------->
<div class="link">With link class</div>
```

Comment: Мне надо что бы сперва взялось их `item1` затем `item0`, потом снова из item1 и так далее. В `item1` и `item0` лежат имена предметов. Как я это думаю сделать, если флаг `true` то вывести 0, если же `false` то 1. Естественно потом там будет задачи в зависимости от какой был флаг

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function (){
  let flag = true;
  let items = [document.getElementById("item0"), document.getElementById("item1")];
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('link')) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      addText(items[+(flag = !flag)], e.target.textContent);  // +Bool === 0 или 1 (Number) 
    }
  });

  function addText(elem, str) {
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <span class="item-sub">${str}</span> 
    `); 
    console.clear(); 
    console.log(`Текст "${str}" добавлен в #${elem.id}`); 
  }
})();
```

```css
h1 { padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.7em; line-height: 1em; min-height: 1em; background-color: #eee; box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px 0 #0004; }
h1:nth-of-type(n+2) { margin-top: -0.5em; }
.item-sub { margin-left: -0.5em; }
.link { font-size: 32px; text-decoration: none; margin-right: 0.5em; padding: 0 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.link:before { content: '+'; display: inline; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link"></a> <a href="#" class="link"></a> <a href="#" class="link"></a>
<h1 id="item0"></h1>
<h1 id="item1"><span class="item-sub"></span></h1>
```

Comment: Когда страница загрузилась то `item0` пустой, а в `item1` лежит название предмета. Когда я кликаю на другой предмет то записывается в `item0`, а `item1` остается прежним. Когда кликаю третий раз, то `item0` остается прежним, а в `item1` записывается название и так далее. Мне надо брать всегда последнее записанное значение и например вывести в консоль, как взять последнее записанное значение? Я это начал делать через флаг. Если флаг `true` то значит 1 и выводим `item1`, если `false` то значит 0 и выводит с `item0`

Comment: @MegaRoks, я обновил ответ (надеюсь, понял верно).